# What is a MURSKY.desktop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox

I was setting up some default .desktop files and happened to come across one titled, `userapp-Firefox-MURSKY.desktop`, which contained the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
Exec=/usr/bin/x-www-browser %u
Name=Firefox
Comment=Custom definition for Firefox
```

The file `x-www-browser` has a note in the beginning:

> *Firefox launcher containing a Profile migration helper for
>   temporary profiles used during alpha and beta phases.*

Does anyone have any idea where this came from?

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x-www-browser` refers to the default system browser set by the Debian Alternatives System (which is a fancy word for a system that basically symlinks default application names like `x-www-browser` to actual programs). By default, this is supposed to be symlinked to Firefox.

`%u` suggests it is supposed to receive a URL as an argument. Thus this `.desktop` file appears to be intended for opening some specific URL.

As for the file itself and where it came from, that's a bit of a mystery. I have not found anything via google searches.  You could delete the file if you're concerned for security, as it is merely a `.desktop` file, aka program shortcut and not an actual program itself. I would suggest you ask on the Firefox/Mozilla forum as well.

Comment: Thanks. I will ask on the Mozilla forum also. Just curious about it. I will post if I find anything out about it.

Comment: Well, we couldn't find out exactly what the file was but it "seems" to have been used for testing. I am going to back it up and delete it from my system.

I may try to investigate it further ... just curious, you know.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Lee what did it intend to test ?

Comment: It looks like it was for testing Firefox during alpha and beta phases. I'm going to back it up and then delete it.

In case you're interested, here is [the link where we discussed it](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=3020189&p=14691587#p14691587)